# Using SVG path in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, svg, uibezierpath

I order to draw a complex line. I am using a Bezier path by:

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CAShapeLayer *shapeView = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
//And set its path:
[shapeView setPath:mybezierPath.CGPath];
//Finally add it:
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:shapeView];
```

How can I pass a a path from a SVG d tag like:

```
d = M418.3,70c-0.2-4.3-1.1-8.4-2.4-12.2c-0.3,0.1-12.3,4.9-52.7,4.9c-40.8,0-51.5-4.9-51.5-4.9c-0.9,2.1-1.5,4.1-1.9,5.7c-1.9,8.3-2.8,23.5-2.5,28.2s1
```

to mybezierPath variable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no default SVG parser in AppKit or UIKit. It is because the `UIBezierPath` or `NSBezierPath` can't cover everything SVG can describe.

You can search for UIBezierPath extensions(categories) that can parse the path from the format that is used in SVG. Or you can write your own parser.